# Faster export of datagridview with colored cells to excel

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have searched and could find only ways to export datagridview to excel without color information. I would like to export the datagridview to excel with the cells coloring intact. Right now, I do it cell by cell and it is very slow. I am looking for a faster way to do it?

Any suggestions or pointers would be really helpful.

Thanks
Mansoor

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Shared Sub ExportGridViewToExcelGridView(ByVal Filename As String, ByRef gvr As GridView, ByRef currentPage As Page)

    Dim HtmlForm As System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm = New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm()
    currentPage.Controls.Add(HtmlForm)
    HtmlForm.Controls.Add(gvr)
    currentPage.Response.Clear()
    currentPage.Response.Buffer = True
    currentPage.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & Filename)
    currentPage.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    currentPage.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    currentPage.Response.Charset = ""
    currentPage.EnableViewState = False
    Using strwriter As New StringWriter
        Dim htmlwrt As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(strwriter)
        HtmlForm.RenderControl(htmlwrt)
        htmlwrt.Flush()
        currentPage.Response.Write(strwriter.ToString)
        currentPage.Response.End()
    End Using
End Sub
```

you can use this function, make sure that you set EnableEventValidation to False in the page containing the gridview and the paging property is set to false..

Comment: I will check this out. But my application is a windows based application, not a web. I am not sure, from where I can get the Page object?

Comment: in windows application you cannot export datagrid faster than do it cell by cell. I thought you are working in web application.

Comment: Thanks @Ron for your help. Without cell color, it can be exported quickly. But with the cell color intact, there does not seem to be any faster way in windows thick client app.